# Gradient and hessian of scalar function which involves polar decomposition

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-decomposition

I need to find gradient and hessian of the following function

$$
\psi(F) = ||F - RC||^2_F
$$
w.r.t $F$. Where $C$ is constant and $R$ comes from polar decomposition of $F = RS$, where $R$ - rotational part and $S$ - "scale", $||A||^2_F$ - just sum of squares of elements of matrix $A$.

Can somebody explain me how to compute such derivative? Also it would be really awesome if somebody can advice me some good mathematical tool for taking derivatives of functions which involves polar decomposition. Maybe matrix differentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}
$Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\ 
}$$
Assume that $R$ is constant so that
$$\eqalign{dF &= R\;dS\qquad\qquad\qquad}$$
and calculate the differential and gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= \big\|F-RC\big\|^2_F \\
 &= \big\|R(S-C)\big\|^2_F \\
 &= \big\|S-C\big\|^2_F \\
 &= (S-C):(S-C) \\
d\psi &= 2(S-C):dS \\
  &= 2(S-C):(R^TR)\,dS \\
  &= 2R(S-C):dF \\
  &= 2(F-RC):dF \\
\grad{\psi}{F} &= 2(F-RC) \\
}$$
Assuming that $S$ is constant $\big(dF=dR\;S\big)$ yields the same result.
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= \big\|R(S-C)\big\|^2_F \\
 &= R(S-C):R(S-C) \\
d\psi &= 2R(S-C):dR\;S \\
 &= 2(F-RC):dF \\
\grad{\psi}{F} &= 2(F-RC) \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for answer! Can i ask you to explain how this "assuming that R is constant" stuff works? I roughly understand how to use differentials (e.g. use fact that dF = RdS + dRS, put it into expression and rearrange). But i have no idea how and then i can declare some variables "constant". Link to some tutorial/textbook will be awesome.

Comment: For books, I'd recomment Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_, or perhaps Hjorungnes's _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_. Or just explore this site − there are lots of interesting questions and answers.